# Why is Python loading extremely slowly in Visual Studio?

Tags: python, visual-studio, load, interpreter

My output is cluttered with hundreds of lines that look like this:

`'python.exe' (Python): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_86\Lib\struct.py'. Module was built without symbols. 'python.exe' (Python): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_86\Lib\ctypes\_endian.py'. Module was built without symbols. 'python.exe' (Python): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_86\Lib\glob.py'. Module was built without symbols. 'python.exe' (Python): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_86\Lib\fnmatch.py'. Module was built without symbols. 'python.exe' (Python): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_86\Lib\posixpath.py'. Module was built without symbols.`

and it takes a minute or two to get to my code. It seems to be loading way more than necessary, including niche libraries that are only tangentially related to what I have imported (just pyqtgraph).

I have tried various solutions, excluding symbols, and trying to specify modules. There doesn't seem to be a clear setting in **Options > Debug** to fix this. I should note that I believe this happened after enabling native debugging for a C++ extension I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, there is currently no "Just My Code" debug option when debugging native code in PTVS (Python for Visual Studio).